# In julia, how do I assign the output of an expression to a new variable?

Tags: julia

Stupid example, I would like to do something like

```
X=println("hi"),
```

and get

```
X="hi".
```

Comment: The purpose of `println` is to print a string to standard output, not to return the string as a result. As it is, your question is unclear. Please give more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general solution is to use `IOBuffer` and `takebuf_string` as described by @ARM above. If it's enough to capture the output of `print`, then

```
s = string(args...)
```

gives the string that would have been printed by `print(args...)`. Also,

```
s = repr(X)
```

gives the string that would have been printed by `showall(X)`. Both are implemented using `IOBuffer` and `takebuf_string` internally.

Answer (score 3):

I think the poster wants to access the nice summary format that you can get from println.  One way to access that as a string is to write to a buffer using print and then read it back as a string.  There's probably also an easier way.

```
using DataFrames
data = DataFrame()
data[:turtle] = ["Suzy", "Suzy", "Bob", "Batman",  "Batman", "Bob", "Adam"]
data[:mealType] = ["bug", "worm", "worm", "bug",  "worm", "worm", "stick"]

stream = IOBuffer()
println(data)
print(stream, data)
yourString = takebuf_string(stream)
```

returns

```
"7x2 DataFrame\n| Row | turtle   | mealType |\n|-----|----------|----------|\n| 1   | \"Suzy\"   | \"bug\"    |\n| 2   | \"Suzy\"   | \"worm\"   |\n| 3   | \"Bob\"    | \"worm\"   |\n| 4   | \"Batman\" | \"bug\"    |\n| 5   | \"Batman\" | \"worm\"   |\n| 6   | \"Bob\"    | \"worm\"   |\n| 7   | \"Adam\"   | \"stick\"  |"
```

Comment: Julia 1.6: `takebuf_string` deprecated I think. By checking `IOBuffer` in the docs I found this is the way: `io = IOBuffer(); show(io, MIME("text/html"),data); yourString = String(take!(io))`.  I used `show` instead of `print` because that was my own use-case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are after formatted strings you can use `@sprintf`.

```
julia> x = @sprintf("%s", "hi")
"hi"

julia> x
"hi"

julia> x = @sprintf("%d/%d", 3, 4)
"3/4"
```

It's a macro though so be careful